# Property [x] does not exist on this collection - laravel

Tags: php, laravel-7

in my function

```
    public function export(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $countDevice = $this->document->where('document_info_id', $id)->count();
        $infos[] = $this->document->where('document_info_id', $id)->get();
        for ($i = 0; $i < $countDevice; $i++) {
            $this->handover->create([
                'document_info_id' => $id,
                'room_id' => $request->room_id,
                'device_name' => $infos[$i]->device_name,
                'device_info' => $infos[$i]->device_info,
                'unit' => $infos[$i]->unit,
                'qty' => $infos[$i]->recommended_unit,
                'note' => $infos[$i]->note
            ]);
        }
    }
```

I get error

> Property [device_name] does not exist on this collection instance.

but when i test

```
    public function export(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $countDevice = $this->document->where('document_info_id', $id)->count();
        $infos[] = $this->document->where('document_info_id', $id)->get();
        for ($i = 0; $i < $countDevice; $i++) {
            dd($infos[$i]);
        }
    }
```

it still returns the result

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1291 ▼
  #items: array:4 [▼
    0 => App\Document_device {#1292 ▼
      #table: "document_devices"
      #guarded: []
      #attributes: array:14 [▼
        "id" => 42
        "document_info_id" => 3
        "device_name" => "Device name 42"
        "device_info" => "xxx"
        "origin" => "US"
        "unit" => null
        "recommended_unit" => 28
        "note" => null
      ]
      #original: array:14 [▶]
    }
    1 => App\Document_device {#1290 ▶}
    2 => App\Document_device {#1288 ▶}
    3 => App\Document_device {#1079 ▶}
  ]
}
```

When i change to use **foreach** it have the same issue.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm trying to change

```
 $infos[] = $this->document->where('document_info_id', $id)->get();
```

to

```
 $infos = $this->document->where('document_info_id', $id)->get();
```

and it work